# Issue with node debugging in docker for node:14-alpine and later

Tags: node.js, docker

I had an issue with not being able to debug a node application running in docker where the dockerfile was based on a tweaked version from an earlier project.

In order to investigate the issue I used a simplified version of the dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

COPY package.json package.json  
RUN npm install

COPY ./index.js .  

CMD ["node", "."]
```

where the contents of index.js were only `console.log('Hello World!')`.

Findings:

`docker build -t debug-test . && docker run debug-test`

> Hello World!

`docker build -t debug-test . && docker run -p "9229:9229" debug-test node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0 index.js`

> Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/c29fa1e4-0256-44ce-898b-45d7b43c667e

but the chrome node debugger does not connect.

I tried lots of permutations of ports, docker compose and mounting of code as volumes without any luck.

Also, used [this](https://github.com/RisingStack/debug-node-docker) repo to establish that chrome debugger was not broken.

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be the base docker image. The original dockerfile I had copied used `node:12-alpine` but I tweaked it to be `node:16-alpine` to match the version of the application I was dockerising. My detective work found that starting from `node:14-alpine` something has changed to egress which prevents debugging.

Switching the base image from an alpine image to `node:16` resolved the problem and allowed debugging of the app running in docker. I'm not clear what the change would have been but if anyone knows I'd be interested.

Comment: Turns out this answer is not correct. Whilst I can repeatably show that debugging works for node:13 in the test app above but does not work for node:14 (regardless of variants such as alpine). I can not get debugging working for this simple demonstration app to work for any node image after node:13.

Comment: Turns out this answer is not completely correct. Whilst I can repeatably show that debugging works for node:13 in the test app above but does not work for node:14 (regardless of variants such as alpine). I can not get debugging working for this simple demonstration app to work for any node image after node:13 to node:16 (inclusive). Debugging in node:17, node:18 and node:latest all work.